# gitlab API to download archive file in git gives bad file but good when called from local machine

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to retrieve a build file using the gitlab API. This file was created and stored as an artifact from an upstream pipeline. Running

`curl -o download --location --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN:{MY_API_TOKEN}' https://gitlab.foo.com/api/v4/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/jobs/artifacts/{REF_BRANCH}/download?job={JOB_NAME}`

on my local machine gives me a proper build file once I run `unzip download`. However in the runner, the same command returns a much smaller file which I can't unzip. I've checked that the environment variables that are passed in the runner are right.

job in .gitlab-ci.yml

```
deploy_production_environment:
  stage: deploy_prod
  image:
    name: banst/awscli

  script:
    - apk --no-cache add curl
    - apk add unzip
    - echo $JOB_ID
    - echo $FE_BUILD_TOKEN
    - echo "https://gitlab.foo.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/jobs/artifacts/${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}/download?job=build_prod"
    - aws configure set region us-east-1
    - "curl -o download --location --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN:${FE_BUILD_TOKEN}' https://gitlab.foo.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/jobs/artifacts/${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}/download?job=build_prod"
    - ls -l
    - unzip download
    - aws s3 cp build s3://$S3_BUCKET_PROD --recursive
```

gitlab job output:

[image]

`

output from my local terminal:

[image]

Why does the API call from inside the runner consistently result in this much smaller (corrupted?) file while the same call pulls the zip file down correctly on my local machine?

Answer (score 1):

The first check to do when a curl brings back a "small" file it to read its content.

Often, the file is not so much corrupted but includes a text-based error message in it, which can give a clue as to the actual issue.

Adding `-v` to the `curl` command can also help illustrating the issue during the curl process (when executed in the context of the GitLab job).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to VonC for the debugging help, recommending the `-v` flag to the `curl` command. It turns out that the single quotes around `'PRIVATE-TOKEN:${FE_BUILD_TOKEN}'` prevented the variable from being parsed to its correct string value which was giving a 401 'Permission Denied' error. Removing the single quotes did the trick.